# Storing a SQL user in a variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've generated some create scripts in SSMS (2014) and as part of the script there are several accounts created.  We will be using different accounts based on whether the db is deployed to test, preproduction or production.

I would like to make it easy for the installer to change the accounts so I thought it would be a good idea if I could store the login(s) and declare this at the very top of the script, however I'm not sure how to go about this.

Currently I have:

```
CREATE USER [RAMBOLL\SVC_D-StructureDB] FOR LOGIN [somedomain\someaccount] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\someaccount]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\someaccount]
GO
```

How can I declare the "somedomain\someaccount" and then reference it in the SQL code above? I tried but SQL didn't like it.

```
DECLARE @SomeAccount VARCHAR(255)
SET @SomeAccount = "[somedomain\someaccount]"

CREATE USER @SomeAccount FOR LOGIN @SomeAccount WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
    GO
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER @SomeAccount
    GO
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER @SomeAccount
    GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These legacy and will-be-removed stored procedures allow parametrisation

- [sp_grantdbaccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178013.aspx)
- [sp_addrolemember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx)

However, I would consider an IF statement if only a few options. Then dynamic SQL if you need more flexibility

```
DECLARE @env VARCHAR(10)
SET @env = 'test'

IF @env = 'test'
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [somedomain\someaccount] FOR LOGIN [somedomain\someaccount] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\someaccount]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\someaccount]
END
ELSE IF @env = 'live'
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [somedomain\liveaccount] FOR LOGIN [somedomain\liveaccount]WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\liveaccount]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [somedomain\liveaccount]
END
...
```